# Same character escape sequences

Tags: c#, regex

I wanna match the number enclosed by braces but the braces themselves are escape sequences, I want the match to begin at the last brace when there's exactly an odd number of 'em.

```
{0}    OK
{{0}   NOT OK
{{{0}  OK
{{{{0} NOT OK
```

I've lookahead/lookbehind assertions like this:

```
(?<!\{\{)
```

But that doesn't match repetitions `{{{0}` and I'm actually unsure wheter this can be done without involving groups and quatifiers. (I'd like it if the assertion wasn't part of the match)

The match has to be able to occur anywhere in a string.

## This is the best I got so far

```
(?<=^|[^\{]|\{\{)\{(?=\w)
```

It succeeds everywhere except for this part `{{{{0}` putting a quantifier on the pair for braces doesn't appear to have any effect. According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx) there shouldn't be a limitation on the subexpression of a zero-width positive lookbehind assertion but it's not having the desired effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your attempt as base, try this:

```
(?<!\{)\{(?:\{\{)*(?=\w)
```

An explanation:

- `(?<!\{)` ensures that there is no `{` preceding
- `\{` matches one `{`
- `(?:\{\{)*` matches zero or more occurrences of `{{` (so always an odd number of `{` in total)
- `(?=\w)` ensures that there is some word character following

Comment: You had to rearrange it a bit for it to work. That part surprised me.

Comment: @John Leidegren: If you’re wondering that I used `\{(?:\{\{)*` instead of `(?:\{\{)*\{`: they’re absolutely equivalent. And `(?…)` is just a group that’s matched string is not referenced (a so called [noncapturing group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#noncapturing_group)).

Comment: But you moved the repetition out of the assertion. I think that was the thing that got me fooled. I was trying to assert with a repetition which I don't think is possible.

Comment: @John Leidegren: Yes, good point. Arbitrary repetition (e.g. `*`, `+`, `{x,}`, etc.) is often not allowed in look-behind assertions due to performance reasons.